# SQL cant alter table with integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

HI i have a sql column and i want to edit it and add a constraint to it but i cant execute my sql statement because it gives the following error
code:

```
ALTER TABLE afdelingen
    ALTER COLUMN anr INTEGER(2) constraint anr_num_gen NOT NULL;
```

error:

```
bedrijf.public> ALTER TABLE afdelingen
                    ALTER COLUMN anr integer(2) constraint anr_num_gen NOT NULL
[2021-09-14 01:47:22] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "integer"
[2021-09-14 01:47:22] Position: 46
```

can someone help me please

Comment: i read the documentation but i couldnt find an answer to why it rejects my INTEGER(2) method. do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

`INTEGER(2)` is not a valid type in Postgres.  Or SQL.  And you need to set the `NOT NULL` separately.  Perhaps:

```
ALTER TABLE afdelingen
    ALTER COLUMN anr TYPE INTEGER,
    ALTER COLUMN anr SET NOT NULL;
```

You might want `SMALLINT` instead.  It is 2 bytes, if that is the intention of the `(2)`.

Comment: what if i want to set the integer to (2) and want to add ```constraint anr_num_gen NOT NULL;``` how do i do it then ?

Comment: the reason i use integer is because i want to use 0 to 99 in that column what do i do then

Comment: @klaasvanburen10 . . . I have no idea what "set the integer to (2)` means.  Are you trying to set a default value?

Comment: @klaasvanburen10 If you want to limit the column to values between 0 and 99, add a `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: i am trial and erroring the past 5 hours and i am just tired of this f**** sh***. i just want to add the sequence to my column anr but it wont work in any way i google in 1000 ways and can't find anything. ```CREATE sequence anr_num_gen
    start with      10
    increment by    10;

ALTER TABLE afdelingen
    ALTER COLUMN anr SET CONSTRAINT anr_num_gen,
    ALTER COLUMN anr SET NOT NULL;``` please help me

Comment: @klaasvanburen10 . . . Perhaps you should ask a *new* question that clearly explains what you are trying to accomplish.